# What is the term for simmering something in sauce?

Tags: sauce, boiling, language

What is the term called for when something, generally meat, is cooked in a large amount of sauce such that the meat is completely submerged.

It is similar to boiling or simmering but instead of water it would be some sort of sauce.

This is one of my favorite ways to cook chicken so that it doesn't end up dry and was wondering the name of this technique so I could look up how other people have done it.

Comment: I think you're referring to braising.

Comment: Is it still braising if the meat is completely submerging? It sounds a bit like poaching to me.

Answer (score 4):

As Tall said, that can be referred to as braising, but generally braising is with liquid that doesn't quite submerge the meat. If the meat is fully submerged, another term is "stewing". Whatever you call it, it is best done at a simmer, not a full boil.